# I can't select multiple objects in the form

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vb6

i've a win 8 machine with vb6 fully updated, but when i make any project in the visual studio, i cant select more than one object that i put.

Because this, i can't align or resize these things.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure in Win 8. Can you hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> button and select other object?